# How to css Backgroud image for option in select on Mobile and Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari

I am trying to style the select options through CSS. It is working great on Chrome but I am facing issues on Safari Browser and Mobile Devices. For some reason, my background image on options is not showing.

```
option[value=icon_1] { 
   background-image: url("images/icon/Icon_1.png");
}
```

On chrome It will show up like this:
[image]

- But on mobile and safari it showing like this :
  [image]

Comment: Would you like to provide a fiddle or snippnet so that I can test it?

Comment: @RedWingJusticeChan  it is here https://jsfiddle.net/chubinh996/qk5wpzxt/8/  
you can fix it for me on mobile devices and safari ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unluckily, the safari may have limitation to achieve this. Therefore, I sugguest not to use select tag, as this tag has lots of limitation in safari or either ie, so use div to make sure the style is correct in safari. Then use jquery to get the select value.

```js
$( ".optionwrapper" ).click(function() {
  var val = $( this ).text();
  alert(val);
});
```

```css
.selectwrapper{
  width: 300px;
  border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.optionwrapper{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:0px;
}

.optionwrapper:before{
  content:'';
      width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
        background-image: url("http://couplelab.webdesign88.com/wp-content/themes/dt-the7-child/images/icon/Icon_1.png");
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectwrapper">

<div class="optionwrapper icon_1">icon_1</div>
<div class="optionwrapper icon_2">icon_2</div>
<div class="optionwrapper icon_3">icon_3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . i will try change it not use select option .... :3